# How to delete when the parameter varies by group without looping? (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Imagine I have these columns in a table:

```
id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
instant datetime NOT NULL,
foreignId bigint NOT NULL
```

For each group (grouped by foreignId) I want to delete all the rows which are 1 hour older than the max(instant). Thus, for each group the parameter is different.

Is it possible without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM    mytable
FROM    mytable mto
WHERE   instant <
        (
        SELECT  DATEADD(hour, -1, MAX(instant))
        FROM    mytable mti
        WHERE   mti.foreignid = mto.foreignid
        )
```

Note double `FROM` clause, it's on purpose, otherwise you won't be able to alias the table you're deleting from.

The sample data to check:

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE
        (
        id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        instant DATETIME NOT NULL,
        foreignID INT NOT NULL
        )

INSERT
INTO    @mytable
SELECT  1, '2009-22-07 10:00:00', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  2, '2009-22-07 09:30:00', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  3, '2009-22-07 08:00:00', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  4, '2009-22-07 10:00:00', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT  5, '2009-22-07 08:00:00', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT  6, '2009-22-07 07:30:00', 2

DELETE
FROM    @mytable
FROM    @mytable mto
WHERE   instant <
        (
        SELECT  DATEADD(hour, -1, MAX(instant))
        FROM    @mytable mti
        WHERE   mti.foreignid = mto.foreignid
        )

SELECT  *
FROM    @mytable

1   2009-07-22 10:00:00.000 1
2   2009-07-22 09:30:00.000 1
4   2009-07-22 10:00:00.000 2
```

Comment: I thought for a long time it was working, but unfortunately your query does nothing.

Comment: Sorry. It wasn't working because of some null fields, now with isnull(nullableField, -1) in the proper place it works

Answer (score 4):

Yep, it's pretty straightforward.  Try this:

```
DELETE mt
FROM   MyTable AS mt
WHERE  mt.instant <= DATEADD(hh, -1, (SELECT MAX(instant) 
                                      FROM MyTable 
                                      WHERE ForeignID = mt.ForeignID))
```

Or this:

```
;WITH MostRecentKeys
AS
(SELECT ForeignID, MAX(instant) AS LatestInstant
FROM MyTable)

DELETE mt
FROM   MyTable AS mt
JOIN   MostRecentKeys mrk ON mt.ForeignID = mrt.ForeignID
       AND mt.Instant <= DATEADD(hh, -1, mrk.LatestInstant)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume when you say '1 hour older than the max(instant)' you mean '1 hour older than the max(instant) **for that foreignId**'.

Given that, there's almost certainly a more succinct way than this, but it will work:

```
DELETE
    TableName
WHERE
    DATEADD(hh, 1, instant) < (SELECT MAX(instant)
                                FROM TableName T2
                                WHERE T2.foreignId = TableName.foreignId)
```

The inner subquery is called a 'correlated subquery', if you want to look for more info. The way it works is that for each row under consideration by the outer query, it is the `foreignId` of *that* row that gets referenced by the subquery.